# Proof of dot product formula.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I can't seem to find a visualized proof for the dot product formula attached by image since I can't format text nicely here. I was hoping someone would show me how. [For example I was watching this video and still everyone just says "Accept it".](https://youtu.be/7_tSddU1VyI?t=251)

Why is dot product not a tag?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty3u6.png

Comment: It essentially follows from the law of cosines. [A proof can be found here.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cosine_Formula_for_Dot_Product#:~:text=If%20c%3E0%2C%20then%20by,%CF%80%E2%9F%B9cos%CE%B8%3D%E2%88%921)

Comment: Personally, I like that formula better as a *definition* of the dot product, then $\sum x_iy_i$ is the "formula" (because it depends on coordinates). Anyway, in order to have a visual proof of why $\sum x_iy_i$ would equal $|x||y|\cos\theta$, we would need a visual interpretation of $\sum x_iy_i$ in the first place. Do you have one in mind? I don't. I think the $\sum x_iy_i$ comes from linearity of $x\cdot y$ and the fact $x\cdot y=0$ for orthogonal vectors, and *these* facts can be illustrated geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

The dot product essentially "multiplies" 2 vectors. If the 2 vectors are perfectly aligned, then it makes sense that multiplying them would mean just multiplying their magnitudes. It's when the angle between the vectors is not 0, that things get tricky. So what we do, is we project a vector onto the other. For the sake of context, let's call the vector we will be projecting on $\vec{v}$ and the vector which will be projected $\vec{w}$. In order to project $\vec{w}$ onto $\vec{v}$, we first imagine $\vec{v}$ is a line, as in we drag out the tip and tail of $\vec{v}$ infinitely in the direction of $\vec{v}$. Now, if we want to project the vector $\vec{w}$, we draw a line perpendicular to our first line, which touches this tip of $\vec{w}$ and we multiply the new vector that is created with $\vec{v}$. I hope the 2 pictures below will help clarify this:[image][image]

Here, the blue vector is $\vec{v}$, the red one is $\vec{w}$ and the black one is (I will call it $\vec{x}$) the projected vector. Now all we need to do is "multiply" our original vector and the projected vector. But to do this, we need to find the magnitude of $\vec{x}$. Using trigonometry, we can see that if we call the angle between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ $\theta$, then we see that $\displaystyle{\cos(\theta) = \frac{||\vec{x}||}{||\vec{w}||}}$. Rearranging this, we get the formula for the magnitude of $\vec{x}$: $||\vec{x}|| = ||\vec{w}||\cos(\theta)$. Finally, we said that the dot product of the vectors which point in the same direction, is the product of their magnitudes. So, we get: $$\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w} = ||\vec{v}|| \, ||\vec{x}||\cos(\theta)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\vec u}{||\vec u||}$ is a vector of length $1$. These can be considered to be vectors with one end point at the origin and the other on the unit $n$-sphere.

The definition of the dot product is:

$$\vec u\cdot\vec v=\sum_\limits{i=1}^n u_iv_i$$.

These two vectors define a plane, and because they can be freely rotated, we can make one lie on the $x$-axis, and the other in the $xy$-plane.

The vector on the $x$ axis now has coordinates $(1,0,\dots,0)$ and the other $(v'_1,v'_2,0,\dots,0)$.

The projection of $\vec v'$ onto $\vec u'$ via $\theta'$ is now $u'_1v'_1=v'_1=\cos\theta'$.